# Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './build/types' is not defined by "exports" in .../node_modules/jest-circus/package.json

Tags: react-native, jestjs, detox, jest-circus

I'm trying to setup detox for e2e testing for my React Native app using jest and jest-circus. I am able to build my iOS app with detox by running `detox build --configuration ios` but have been unable to run the sample `firstTest.e2e.js` test with `detox run --configuration ios`. I get the following error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './build/types' is not defined by "exports" in [project path]/node_modules/jest-circus/package.json

      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/detox/runners/jest-circus/listeners/DetoxCoreListener.js:11:25)

detox[92379] ERROR: [cli.js] Command failed: jest --config e2e/config.json --testNamePattern '^((?!:android:).)*$' --maxWorkers 1 e2e
```

My package.json has the following libraries installed:

`"detox": "^18.12.1",`

`"jest": "^24.9.0",`

`"jest-circus": "^27.1.0",`

My .detoxrc.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "testRunner": "jest",
  "runnerConfig": "e2e/config.json",
  "apps": {
    "ios": {
      "type": "ios.app",
      "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/appname.app",
      "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/appname.xcworkspace -scheme appname -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build EXCLUDED_ARCHS=arm64"
    }
  },
  "devices": {
    "simulator": {
      "type": "ios.simulator",
      "device": {
        "type": "iPhone 11"
      }
    }
  },
  "configurations": {
    "ios": {
      "device": "simulator",
      "app": "ios"
    }
  }
}
```

and my e2e/config.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "testEnvironment": "./environment",
    "testRunner": "jest-circus/runner",
    "testTimeout": 120000,
    "testRegex": "\\.e2e\\.js$",
    "reporters": ["detox/runners/jest/streamlineReporter"],
    "verbose": true
}
```

This is a fairly old project, and I am already using jest for unit testing. I wonder if there might be some other configuration file interfering with my e2e config but can't seem to figure it out just yet. Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

you should try another jest-circus version:

```
"jest": "^26.0.1",
"jest-circus": "^26.0.1",
```